# Pre Check the radio button according to value of Day

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have assigned content to few Radio buttons which when clicked will show content of it. I would like to pre-check the tab button according to day.

For eg. if today is Sun, on page load it would show contents of Sunday and if it is Tuesday, then on page load it would show the contents of Tuesday.

My code below:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
  background: #E5E4E2;
}

.tabinator {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.tabinator input {
  display: none;
}

.tabinator label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.tabinator label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tabinator label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}

#content1,
#content2,
#content3,
#content4,
#content5,
#content6,
#content7 {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 15px;
}

#tab1:checked~#content1,
#tab2:checked~#content2,
#tab3:checked~#content3,
#tab4:checked~#content4,
#tab5:checked~#content5,
#tab6:checked~#content6,
#tab7:checked~#content7 {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabinator">

  <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Sunday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Monday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab3" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Tuesday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab4" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">Wednesday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab5" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab5">Thursday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab6" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab6">Friday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab7" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab7">Saturday</label>

  <div id="content1">
    <p>
      This is Sunday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
    <p>This is Monday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content3">
    <p>This is Tuesday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content4">
    <p>This is Wednesday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content5">
    <p>This is Thursday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content6">
    <p>
      This is Friday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content7">
    <p>
      This is Saturday
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you forgot to add your code?!!!!

Comment: I was struggling through code format. Sorry guys. So  I have edited my question. Please have a look at it. I am banging my head around but no luck.

Comment: No need to include the css.

Comment: yes indeed finally I did...now help me out guys.how to I automatically show the tab on page load according to today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do this:

1. Get the current day - this matches the index of the list of radio buttons - so you can do this:

   ```
   $('.tabinator input[name=tabs]').eq(new Date().getDay()).prop('checked', true);
   ```
2. A few of the `label`s for the `radio` weren't correctly labelled - fixed that too.

If you want to show the tab for *tomorrow*, you can try this:

```
$('.tabinator input[name=tabs]').eq(new Date().getDay() + 1).prop('checked', true);
```

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.tabinator input[name=tabs]') // get all tabs
    .eq(new Date().getDay()) // select the current tab
    .prop('checked', true); // check it
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Open+Sans:400,600,700');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
  background: #E5E4E2;
}

.tabinator {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.tabinator input {
  display: none;
}

.tabinator label {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.tabinator label:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -11px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.tabinator label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label {
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tabinator input:checked+label:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}

#content1,
#content2,
#content3,
#content4,
#content5,
#content6,
#content7 {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
  padding: 15px;
}

#tab1:checked~#content1,
#tab2:checked~#content2,
#tab3:checked~#content3,
#tab4:checked~#content4 #tab5:checked~#content5,
#tab6:checked~#content6,
#tab7:checked~#content7 {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tabinator">

  <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Sunday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Monday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab3" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Tuesday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab4" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">Wednesday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab5" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab5">Thursday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab6" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab6">Friday</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tab7" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab7">Saturday</label>

  <div id="content1">
    <p>
      This is Sunday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
    <p>This is Monday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content3">
    <p>This is Tuesday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content4">
    <p>This is Wednesday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content5">
    <p>This is Thursday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content6">
    <p>
      This is Friday
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content7">
    <p>
      This is Saturday
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SagarRawal let me know your thoughts on this, thanks! Please upvote / accept and close the question too if you find it apt!

Comment: indeed it is exactly what i want and it runs smoothly wherever I test it, but It didn't work out for me when I pasted the code in text editor and run on my Opera browser. It loads sunday by default. Wasn't i supposed to enclosed $('.tabinator input[name=tabs]').eq(new Date().getDay()).prop('checked', true); inside <script> and </script> . I'm doing same but no luck again.

Comment: @SagarRawal you need to include jquery too?

Comment: yes I did that too, I thought might be the problem, hence I downloaded it and put on my js folder and link from this   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.min.js"> and still it dosen't load the current day but when I tested same method in online fiddle or editor. It works.

Comment: Maybe scripts' running before page loads - write it inside `$(document).ready(function(){});`... see edited answer

Comment: @SagarRawal and it is `<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>`... `link` is for css